# ACF Field Wordpress - Custom Shortcode Problems

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, visual-composer

I have a small problem
I wrote a simple shortcode function to display my acf value in the grid of the visual grid composer, this is my simple custom shortcode

```
function my_module_add_grid_shortcodes( $shortcodes ) {
    $shortcodes['vc_say_hello'] = array(
     'name' => __( 'Say Hello', 'my-text-domain' ),
     'base' => 'vc_say_hello',
     'category' => __( 'Content', 'my-text-domain' ),
     'description' => __( 'Just outputs Hello World', 'my-text-domain' ),
     'post_type' => Vc_Grid_Item_Editor::postType(),
  );
   return $shortcodes;
}

    add_shortcode( 'vc_say_hello', 'vc_say_hello_render' );
    function vc_say_hello_render() {
             if( get_field('item')  ): 
                 the_field('item');  
                else:
                echo "<h2>ITEM LOCKED</h2>"; 
             endif; 

    }
```

When I call the shortcode in the builder, "ITEM Locked" is displayed, even if the value of the element is set in the post !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like get_field doesn't know where to get it from in the shortcode. Try adding the current post id as the second parameter

```
add_shortcode( 'vc_say_hello', 'vc_say_hello_render' );
function vc_say_hello_render() {
    $id = get_the_ID();
    if( get_field('item', $id)  ): 
        the_field('item', $id);  
    else:
        echo "<h2>ITEM LOCKED</h2>"; 
    endif; 
}
```